# Insert multiple lines into a file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to insert multiple lines into a .json file after a specific pattern using shell script. Also need to consider to insert on the nth occurrence.

Let us consider my input file contents are: input.txt:

```
[ 
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d"
  },
  {
    "e": "e",
    "f": "f"
  }
]
```

In my first case, I have to insert below two lines after the first occurrence of pattern **"},"**  and in my second case the same two lines after the second occurrence of pattern **"},"** in the input.txt file

After inserting my file should change like this:

**First case:** Inserting **x & y** entries

```
[ 
   {
     "a": "a",
     "b": "b"
   },
   {
     "x": "x",
     "y": "y"
   },
   {
     "c": "c",
     "d": "d"
   },
   {
     "e": "e",
     "f": "f"
   }
]
```

**Second case:** Inserting **m & n** entries

```
[ 
   {
     "a": "a",
     "b": "b"
   },
   {
     "c": "c",
     "d": "d"
   },
   { 
     "m": "m",
     "n": "n"
   }
   {
     "e": "e",
     "f": "f"
   }
]
```

I am trying this with **sed** command in my shell scipt. But this always replaces in the **first occurrence** and **not the nth** **occurrence**.

```
sed -e '0,/},/{//a\  {\n    "x",\n    "y"\n  },' -e '}' input.txt file
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: You should consider using ``jq``

Comment: None of your examples is valid JSON. JSON uses brackets `[]` for arrays, and curly braces `{}` for objects, but what is inside your curly braces looks more like an array.

Comment: Your final result is missing the `,` before the last array element.

Comment: Manipulating JSON with text tools is very dangerous, it's really hard to get all the cases correct. In particular, whether to add a comma depends on whether you're inserting in the middle or at the end of an array or object, and this is hard to check with tools like `sed`. You really should use something that parses and formats JSON, like `jq`.

Comment: You aren't inserting lines into your file. You are inserting a new object into the array contained in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) it'd as simple as

```
jq '.[:1] + [{"x":"x", "y":"y"}] + .[1:]' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y_kVsduN1w)

and

```
jq '.[:2] + [{"m":"m", "n":"n"}] + .[2:]' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HVhxSeHaM8)

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something that you are planning to reuse you can do it in python.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import json
import sys

j = json.load(sys.stdin)
j.insert(int(sys.argv[1]), json.loads(sys.argv[2]))
print(j)
```

and you can invoke it passing the position and object as parameters

```
./json-insert 1 '{"x": "x", "y": "y"}' < input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cat file.json|tr '\n' ' '| sed 's/},/},{"x":"x", "y":"y"},/2'|json_pp
[
   {
      "a" : "a",
      "b" : "b"
   },
   {
      "c" : "c",
      "d" : "d"
   },
   {
      "x" : "x",
      "y" : "y"
   },
   {
      "e" : "e",
      "f" : "f"
   }
]
```

#--------------------------------------------------------------

```
cat file.json|tr '\n' ' '| sed 's/},/},{"x":"x", "y":"y"},/2'|json_pp > tmp.json
mv tmp.json file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -Ee '/\}/{x;s/^/x/;/^x{1}$/{x;r /dev/stdin' -e 'x};x}' file
  {
    "x": "x",
    "y": "y"
  },
!
```

or:

```
cat <<\! | sed -Ee '/\}/{x;s/^/x/;/^x{2}$/{x;r /dev/stdin' -e 'x};x}' file
  {
    "m": "m",
    "n": "n"
  },
!
```

Pipe strings to be inserted via `/dev/stdin` into a sed invocation, using a counter in the hold space to initiate the placement of the strings.

N.B. The `r` command has to be terminated by a newline, hence the reason for splitting the sed commands into two parts using the `-e` command option. The strings can be collected in a here-document and passed to `/dev/stdin` of the following pipe using the `cat` command.